# TAG Merge : snapshot and snapshots

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I think these 2 should be merged

[snapshot](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/snapshot)
[snapshots](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/snapshots)

Comment: I wonder if perhaps there should be a system rule to automatically merge or synonym plurals to the non-plural version of the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done: Merged and created synonyms.